# How do you indent/outdent items in a custom list with Task Content Type?

Tags: custom-list

I had to create a custom list (with content type of Task) instead of creating a task list because of another issue where task lists will not allow filtering in the calendar view. Now I'm running into an issue where the Indent/Outdent (i.e. Hierarchy options) are not available for my custom list. Is there any way to add the indent/outdent options to a custom list?

It looks like I also can't add items in the custom list to the timeline. Is there any way to add these functions to a custom list?

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that some other users have asked the similar questions... But the Hierarchy as well as the Timeline options are available for the Tasks list. They are the Tasks list features, not for other lists. So, using a custom list to achieve the goal as a Tasks list is not feasible. Hope the information can help you sort out the query. Good Luck, buddy~